# Como calcular el porcentaje en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, porcentaje

Tengo una pequeña duda. Estaba terminando de programar una calculadora sin usar `eval()` y me topé con algo que me ha dejado una duda:

```js
4/1% o 2/5%
```

La primera operación da 400 y la segunda 40. Exactamente, ¿cómo se realiza esta operación?

Por lo tengo entendido, el `1%` es igual que decir `1*4/100` porque es el `1%` de `4`. Para simplificar la operación sería:

```js
(4) / ( (1*4)/(100) )
```

Por lo que esto da `100` y `2/5%` es igual a `40`. `2*5/100` es equivalente a `2%` de `5`.

No sé si estoy ejecutando mal la operación. Pero agradezco que me ayuden a definir una operación que sea capaz de sacar el procentaje en distinas probabilidades. Es decir, `2+2%`, `2-2%`, `3/4%`, `3*3%`, etc. Pongo como ejemplo el código de la calculadora que estoy haciendo [aquí](https://codepen.io/pen/?template=poEoLNe). Aún no logro realizar bien las operaciones de porcentaje.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

La función x% lo que hace es dividir la x por 100, por lo cual tu estas haciendo 4/(1/100) que seria 4/0.01 lo cual da 400.

Para calcular el porcentaje lo puedes hacer multiplicando simplemente, aquí te dejo unos ejemplos:

- El 1% de 4 = 4*(1/100) = 4*0.01 = 0.04
- El 5% de 2 = 2*(5/100) = 2*0.05 = 0.1
- El 120% de 8 = 8*(120/100) = 8*1.2 = 9.6

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias José, pude resolver mi problema, solo tenia que mejorar el orden en que se dan las operaciones

Answer (score 1):

Estas cometiendo un error en el orden jerárquico de las operaciones al hacer tu comprobación. Tus operaciones están correctas.

Voy a tratar de hacer un análisis (si bien recuerdo). De lo que esta pasando.

> Dado que tienes `4/1%` = `4 / (1/100)` = `4 / 0.01` = `400`
>
> Dado que tienes `2/5%` = `2 / (5/100)` = `2 / 0.05` = `40`

Esto se resuelve así por que al "expandir" `1%` debes conservar su jerarquía dentro de la operación. Esto se logra con los paréntesis. `1% = (1/100)`

Por lo demás. Pon tu código directo en tu pregunta. Tu link no esta funcionando.
Editando...

Comment: bueno ya resolvi el problema hace unas horas. Exactamente como me comentas tu y José, el 2% es igual a 2/100 , pero a la hora de realizar las siguientes operaciones Ejemp: 2+2% ----> 2+(2*2)/100 , lo que da 2.04, y si invertimos el orden 2% + 2 -----> 2/100 + 2 lo que da 2.02. Exactamente eso me tenia algo confundido, lo que es crear una expresion regular que solo afecta a sumas y restas y se soluciono el problema.

Comment: Acerca del link, nose la verdad, ese enlace lo he copiado desde mi pen de codepen que me dice que se puede compartir con demas usuarios. Si no funciona ese, aca dejo otro https://codepen.io/Husdady/pen/poEoLNe